# Equivalent of InputParser on an Older Version of Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am currently running an older version of Matlab - 7.0.4 to be exact, and I'm trying to convert code that involves the newer InputParser into code that would work with this older version. I was wondering if there are any similar commands like inputParser that could be used.

This is the section of code that I'm struggling to convert.

```
p=inputParser;
p.addParamValue('clusters', repmat(2,k,1), @(x)isvector(x) && length(x)==k);
p.addParamValue('numit', 1000, @(x)x>0 && mod(x,1)==0);
p.addParamValue('abort', 1e-10, @(x)x>=0);
p.addParamValue('verbose', true, @islogical);
p.addParamValue('verbosecompact', true, @islogical);
p.parse(varargin{:});
res=p.Results;
r=res.clusters;
if res.verbose
    fprintf('starting graphclustering of %i-partite graph with partition sizes: ',k);
    disp(n');
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to InputParser I used to use 50 to 100 lines of code at the beginning of some complex functions.  (Or you can try to roll your own equivalent of the InputParser class.)

Manual input handling is not hard, just a little tedious.  The code woudl look something like:

```
%Check for Clusters
ix = find(cellfun(@(x)strcmpi(x,'clusters'),varargin));
if ~isempty(ix) && (ix+1)<length(varargin)
    rec.clusters = varargin{ix+1};
else
    rec.clusters = repmat(2,k,1);
end

%Check for 'numit'
% ... following the template above
```

---

That will work.  For extra credit,. and improved maintainability, you can define the a cell array or structure of with parameter names and default values, and write a loop over that structure, rather than copying the same template code and risking copy/paste errors.

---

Edit:
This purports to be an example of an input parsing function.  I have not tested it, but it may be somewhere to start.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10670-parseargs-simplifies-input-processing-for-functions-with-multiple-options